# Horizontal align text and image avatars

Tags: html, css

I have a simple horizontal box with multiple round avatars. The avatar will   either be an image or a CSS circle, but all elements should be aligned in a single row with text centered inside the non-image circles.

I can't get this to happen.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lilbiscuit/dqsnbma5/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="circle" style="left:0;">1</div>
  <img  src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/887828156886986752/F7XIdhSg_400x400.jpg" />
  <div class="circle" >KU<div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.outer {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  position:relative;
}
img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

How do I get these avatars to appear in a straight row?

Comment: Take a look --> https://jsfiddle.net/dqsnbma5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `vertical-align: top;` to your `.circle` element. This will align all items vertically to the top.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqsnbma5/2/

Answer (score 2):

use can use `display:inline-flex` on `.outer`

```
.outer {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-flex;
}
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/dqsnbma5/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try css [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <img class="circle" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/887828156886986752/F7XIdhSg_400x400.jpg" />
  <div class="circle">KU</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consolidate your styles for `img` and `.circle` like so, then add a few rules to achieve your desired effect:

1. `vertical-align: top` to ensure that `display: inline-block` elements are aligned on the Y-axis
2. `text-align: center` to get the text horizontally centered within the circles
3. `line-height: 60px` to get the text vertically centered within the circles

Live demo below:

```css
.outer {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle,
img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/887828156886986752/F7XIdhSg_400x400.jpg" />
  <div class="circle">KU</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="circle" style="left:0;">1</div>
  <img  src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/887828156886986752/F7XIdhSg_400x400.jpg" />
  <div class="circle" >KU</div>
</div>
```